I am trying to install Ubuntu on my Windows 11 machine and getting this error code: Class not registered Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
I want to look into some computer vision work and am currently trying to install Ubuntu on my pc so I can more easily work with OpenCV through Python.
However, I'm running into an issue with my computer seemingly unable to recognize that the windows subsystem for linux is enabled. Trying to install wsl through powershell or CMD gives me this error:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --install
Class not registered
Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
If I download the ubuntu application and try to run it I am met with this:
ubuntu error
However, the WSL is enabled as you can see here, as is the Virtual Machine Platform
Windows Features
I interestingly do not have an option for Hyper-V which seems like an issue in and of itself. And I have enabled Virtualization through the BIOS.
I have found threads of other people who are seemingly facing a similar issue (or the same one), however, none have been given a solution that worked. I'm at a loss of how to get this working and could really use some help.
Below are the links of these threads, I've already gone through these suggestions step by step.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1531229/enable-windowsoptionalfeature-feature-name-microso
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowserver/forum/all/hyper-v-not-showing-up/86eadef9-8c32-493c-9a66-0c170b075d08
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5182
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1152199/wslregisterdistribution-failed-with-error-0x800701

You need to be installing WSL using the install command instead of enabling it through the Windows Feature GUI. Hyper-V is absolutely not required for WSL. Uninstall everything through Windows Feature, reboot your system, and install it properly.

Hey Ramhound, Installing WSL through the CMD was how I started. That is where I got the initial error of:
C:\Windows\System32>wsl --install
Class not registered
Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
I uninstalled, restarted, and ran the command and still get this error.

Install this version of WSL. You will want to install Virtual Machine Platform, manually, before you do to prevent it from failing for other reasons.

Thank you RamHound, That version of wsl was all that I needed to get things working. Could you lend any insight on how you knew the correct version or why the default was causing issues? The more I know for the future, the better

@AlistairByrne - I used Google to find a GitHub issue that explains the precise reason you were getting that error.

@Ramhound Nice job using your Google-fu to find a solution! Reminds me of finding a needle in a haystack while blindfolded and riding a unicycle! :)

@VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle - It was the first result. It wasn’t exactly difficult to find.


Trying to install wsl through powershell or CMD gives me this error:
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> wsl --install Class not registered Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG

Back in December 2023 there was a know issue that caused this error.

There is currently a bug causing WSL to fail to install if the 'Windows subsystem for Linux' optional component is disabled. We're working on a fix but in the meantime can you try to enable that optional component, reboot, and see if that solves the issue ?

In order to resolve this issue. Using an abbreviated solution.  Enable Virtual Machine Platform, reboot your system, then install the current stable release here
Source: Error code: Wsl/CallMsi/REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG #10882
